# Reading auth.log files from a php file and displaying it on web page

Tags: php, server, grep, zgrep, auth.log

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server, and have been trying to create a php file that searches through auth.log for certain attributes and then displays them onscreen.

The php file has permission 644 and root:root as the owner:group.
The auth.log file is default and stored in /var/log with permissions 640 and syslog:adm as owner:group.

The code in index.php is as follows:

```
$output = shell_exec("zgrep 'Invalid' /var/log/auth.log"); 
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

echo exec('whoami'); //This returns as www-data
```

I've tried changing the owner:group on the php file to match the auth.log file but this doesn't seem to change anything.
Any ideas on why this can't return the file details?

Comment: have you tried that zgrep command directly? does it need options?

Comment: Yes, the zgrep provides me with the correct results, but only from root or a sudo account. I believe this may be to do with the permissions of the auth.log

Comment: and your error ? can you show it? and maybe php settings made shell_exec command disabled?

Comment: The shell_exec command is not disabled, I tried it with a simple ls and it displayed all the files. When I run the php file I do not get any feedback, it just displays an empty page.

Comment: Can't get the image to load into the post sorry - but when I insert the zgrep command without root or sudo privileges I get the error : "gzip: /var/log/auth.log: Permission denied"

Comment: And possibly: use which zgrep, then: f.i. /usr/bin/zgrep <command> ?

Comment: Or use sudo , but you don't want that i guess.. Think it is with rights the issue